# Failing connect to DB

Tags: php

I imported a database to my PHPmyadmin in which works well but when I try to display with

my php file, i don't get true, the only I see is the field's line on the top.

hier is my app;

```
<?php

  DEFINE('db_name', 'root');
  DEFINE('db_pass', 'root');
  DEFINE('db_host', 'localhost');
  DEFINE('db_database','SCV_DB');

  $dbcon =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "SCV_DB");

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $color=' well come to mysql';
  echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
  echo 'M. Mori ' . $color.'<br>';
  mysqli_set_charset($dbcon,"utf8");

  echo "<table><tr><th>SECTION</th><th>NAME</th><th>DATE</th><th>COUNTRY</th><th>PREIS</th></tr>";
  $consult="SELECT * FROM TABLE 1"; 

  $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$consult);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row[0]."</td><td>";
    echo $row[1]."</td><td>";
    echo $row[2]."</td><td>";
    echo $row[3]."</td><td>";
    echo $row[4]."</td></tr>";
  }

  echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Pretty sure `SELECT * FROM TABLE 1` is a syntax error. You need to either properly  quote that identifier, or - probably preferable - use a better table name than `1` to begin with.

Comment: Show us what output you are getting

Comment: perhaps our table name is incorrect. what is the output of your query if you run it in mysql.

This should give you a head start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate mysqli procedural style, you should be using Object oriented style much more usefull [here you can find more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Anyway! I was playing with procedural connections and saw your question hope its not a dupliacte one :)

So here is connetction file what I was playing with! you can use your own connection.

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'SCV_DB';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$port = '3308'; //Or 3307
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);  
$dbcon  = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port, $charset);


if ($dbcon ->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbcon ->connect_error);
}
```

Here is the query with prepare statements (prepare statements avoid you from sql injections espacialy when updating and inserting data)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM YourTableName';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbcon ,$sql);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
$getResult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getResult)){
        echo "id: ".$rows['id'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "First name: ".$rows['first_name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Last name: ".$rows['last_name'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: guys, I tried both app but nothing solve my problem.

Comment: Really I don't know how can I link a database in this pot, already I look on the help but I couldn't find anything to clarfying me. any idea?

Comment: @Axel add into question , search for export database, export your table and add it into question other ways no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  DEFINE('db_name', 'root');
  DEFINE('db_pass', 'root');
  DEFINE('db_host', 'localhost');
  DEFINE('db_database','SCV_DB');

  $dbcon =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "SCV_DB");

  // Check connection
  if (!$dbcon) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  echo "Connected successfully";

  $color=' well come to mysql';
  echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
  echo 'M. Mori ' . $color.'<br>';
  mysqli_set_charset($dbcon,"utf8");
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>SECTION</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>COUNTRY</th>
            <th>PREIS</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    $consult="SELECT * FROM TABLE 1";//Please Don't these name for table name  
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$consult);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)):?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>";
        <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>";
        <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>";
        <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>";
        <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>";
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </table>

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hier is the database;[image]

I hope this help for solve the problem.

Comment: You realy need to watch some tutorials how to insert, update, select database, and create table, import or export databse, before asking questions see this is the first step for export database table https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V-ueeRpJOQ that picture looks like an word excel.

Answer (score 0):

I should in the first post explained better my problem. Well this file was an excel file.xls and i use Mac,so to use that in phpmyadmin, first i should convert it to CSV file than importe it, that wasn't any problem because i can see perfectly the database in phpmyadmin but when I try to display it by php in the browser, I don't

get true.

Answer (score 0):

just renaming the table solved the problem.